# MySQL group by - last row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT a.id AS productId, b.*
                FROM #__something AS a
                LEFT JOIN #__somthingElse AS b 
                    ON a.id=b.product_id AND b.accept=1 AND b.user_id = 12 
                WHERE a.id IN (95,86,85)
```

and I'm getting the following

```
85 ........... first
85 ........... second time same id
85 ........... last same id
86 ...........
95 ........... first 
95 ........... last same id
```

by using 'GROUP BY a.id' I'm getting the fist row only per id.

How can I got only the last one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to define "last one". Only the Id is not enough information to define what would be first and last. Some date column, sell date, auto generated id, etc.

Comment: You can add order by id and limit 1 condition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The conditions on LEFT JOIN ON occur multiple times for every a.id, and the first one on the results is just the first on the record. The rest of the data can't help. I've read something about max() that possible can help. With the limit 1 I'm getting only one row as a result.

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "last one" as requested.  You still have not done so.  What we can say is this -- "last one" has nothing to do with table a.  The data for table a is the same for every result, per the nature of the join.  So there must be something in table b, that constitutes what you are describing as "last" one.

Comment: I also would suggest that you move the WHERE criteria up to the ON since that is intrinsic to the result set.  ON a.id=b.product_id AND b.accept=1 AND b.user_id = 12 AND a.id IN (95, 86, 85) -- and omit the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks, but, there is nothing other than some prices, shipping cost, etc. that can't help me. The first one of every id on the results, it's just the first row of the b table that meet the conditions.

Comment: You either don't understand how your own query works, don't understand joins, or you don't understand the question we keep asking you.   In your join there is NOTHING in table A other than the id.  You will get at least one row for every row in A due to your LEFT OUTER JOIN.  In the case where there are  matching rows in b, you will get a row for every matching B row.  So there HAS to be some column in B that constitutes the "last row" criteria.  Because SQL results have no order, until an ORDER BY, any resulting order should not be relied upon.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your help, yes, I don't understand all of the above as you mention. This is not my query, I'm just trying to change a couple of thinks on a plug-in. There is also an b.id that is possibly what you're asking for.

Comment: Keep also in mind that I'm using google translation to read part of your comment plus spell checkers etc

Comment: for the record: From your comments above, I suppose that you can't help me. I understand you need more information to provide answers. But, when someone says that there is nothing else in the table b is probably because there is nothing else in the table b. Unfortunately I can't provide pictures from my DB. Possibly MySql executes an incomplete query and decides to give an order of some sort. I don't know. Anyways, thanks for trying guys.